# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException when trying to load XML file via OLEDB

Tags: xml, oledb

**Error received:**

*Unrecognized database format 'C:\Documents and Settings\YepMyUserName\Local Settings\Temp\tmp1E1.tmp'. --->  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unrecognized database format 'C:\Documents and Settings\YepMyUserName\Local Settings\Temp\tmp1E1.tmp'..*

**Code:**

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}", filename)))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    ....
```

Exception is thrown at connection.Open. I have only found one post on how to load XML file this way and apparently it didn't help.

Please help.

Comment: To be honest I've not see XML loaded via Jet this way. Would be interested to get a link to the post you found, or some other example where it is described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load XML into an ADO.Net dataset you can use the `DataSet.ReadXxml()` method, which will either take a file path or a stream/reader. You can provide it with XML schemas etc as well. There's more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).